# Couls someone explain why i get this error? "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, json, express, model-view-controller

I'm new to Node js and i have a function that receives a json object with numeric values, that i try to add up and display the result on the browser using a "Sum" property. The problem occurs at the mathsServer.js (split() method in the addera()). I do not understand why i suddenly get this error especially when i modified my code according to a MVC. When i run it independently in one file it worked well at some point. Here is my code.
Im supposed to POST a json in postman:

{
"tal": "10,343,24,345,22,23,233, 45, 200,500"
}

router.js:

```
 const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const controller = require("./controllers/controller");
    
    router.post("/add", controller.renderSum)
    
    router.get("/add",controller.renderSum)
    
    
    module.exports = router
```

controller.js:

```
 const mathServerModel = require("../../../mathServer/model/mathModel");    
    
    exports.renderSum = (req, res) => {  
           
        mathServerModel.addera(req.body.tal)
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //res.send({data});
                res.render("post-tal", {
                    Sum: {data}        // A property called Sum to be displayed on the browser
                })
    
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        
    }
```

mathModel.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const addera = async (tal) => {
    let strNumbersArr = tal.split(","); // ["10", "343", "24", ..., "233"]
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < strNumbersArr.length; i++) {
        let currentNumberStr = strNumbersArr[i];
        sum += Number(currentNumberStr); // convert current number string into a number
    }
    return sum;
    
}

module.exports = {
    addera
}
```

index.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>WebApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <style>
        .eNavAction {cursor:pointer}
        .buttons {margin-top: 20px}
    </style>
    <script src="js/simple-helper.js"></script>
    <script src="model/customer-model.js"></script>
    <script src="view/customer-view.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/main-controller.js"></script>
   <script>
        
        var Current = {};
        const Model = new TeamsModel();
        const View = new TeamView();
        const ViewTal = new TalView();
        const Controller = new MainController();

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           // Controller.init();
           Helper.onClassClick('eNavAction',Controller.navAction);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar is-link" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/">
                <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px"  href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/">My Web App</span>
            </a>
        </div>
              
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <a class="eNavAction navbar-item" action ="teams" href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/">Teams</a>
                <a class="navbar-item" action= "tal">Sum</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="section">
        <div id="main-container">
            <div class="enterTal">
                <div class="displaySum">
                
                    <p>Sum is: {{Sum}}</p>

                </div>

            </div>     
            
        </div>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears in controller.js req.body doesn't have an object tal (req.body.tal). You must start your investigation there. mathServerModel.addera() call is passing Undefined object as parameter.

In mathsServer.js, make your code defensive, by first checking your parameters' validity. Check if they have the values and types you were expecting before going into your function's logic.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. However, i noticed that i wrongly named mathModel.js as mathsServer.js..Secondly, i'm not sure i really understand you what you mean. My Node js knowledge is limited, that's why i need help to understand the problem. 
I start the app.js, Enter the json in Postman, then router.js invokes----> controller.js------mathModel.js---controller.js----Browser. I'm stuck, please advice.

Comment: What I meant was, in controller.js:
implement as if condition to check if you have the tal in place.

 exports.renderSum = (req, res) => {  
        if(!request.body.tal){
        //log an error on on console or somewhere else.
        return; //Proceeding further will result in errors since tal is not in place.
       }
        mathServerModel.addera(req.body.tal)

Also implement a similar check in mathModel.js, under
const addera = async (tal) => {
if(!tal) //log and return
....